# cakephp3 condition based associations not works

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am using hasOne association.Here my code for UserMastersTable :

```
class UserMastersTable extends Table {
public function initialize(array $config) {
parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('user_masters');
 $this->hasOne('PersonMasters', [
            'className' => 'PersonMasters',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_master_id',
            'conditions' => ['PersonMasters.status' => 1],
            'dependent' => true,

        ]);
} }
```

When use find() in my controller.It fetch all user_masters data and person_masters data whose `status ='1'`.

but problem is that i already assign condition where association bind..already give condition that only display that data whose `person_masters.status=1`.

so why it shows all data of user_masters ?

if i give condition in find() in controller then it works fine..

```
$this->UserMasters->find('all', 
                         ['contain' => 
                            ['PersonMasters'],
                          'conditions' => 
                            ['PersonMasters.status' => 1]
                         ]);
```

so, how can i globally give condition that only fetch data of user_masters and person_masters where `PersonMasters.status=1`?

Comment: Do you want to apply condition in your associative data ?

Comment: yes ..but i want to give condition to two models globally,not in every query

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be it will resolve your issue

```
$this->UserMasters->find('all',[
                     'contain' => 
                        ['PersonMasters' => [
                           'conditions' => ['status' => 1]
                        ]
                     ],

                     ]);
```